# Не выводятся данные, выводит только Process finished with exit code 0. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, web-scraping

**Python**. Не выводятся данные, выводит только `Process finished with exit code 0`

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    URL = 'https://www.avito.ru/schelkovo/avtomobili/audi/a6-ASgBAgICAkTgtg3elyjitg3onSg?cd=1&radius=200'
    HEADERS = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/;q=0.8'}
    HOST = 'https://www.avito.ru/'
    
    
    def get_html(url, params=''):
        r = requests.get(url)
        return r
    
    
    def get_content(html):
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        items = soup.find_all('div', class_='iva-item-root-Nj_hb')
        cars = []
        for item in items:
            cars.append({
                'title': item.find('div', class_='iva-item-titleStep-_CxvN').find_next('a').find_next('h3').get_text(strip=True),
                'link': item.find('div', class_='iva-item-titleStep-_CxvN').find_next('a').get('href'),
                'price': item.find('span', class_= 'price-text-E1Y7h').get_text(),
                'facts': item.find('div', class_= 'iva-item-text-_s_vh').get_text(),
                'city': item.find('div', class_= 'geo-georeferences-Yd_m5').find_next('span').get_text(),
            })
        return cars
    
    
    
    def parse():
        html = get_html(URL)
        #print(html.content) #непосредственно всё, что находится на странице
        #print(html.headers.get('content-type')) #узнать то, в каком виде зашифрована информация
        if html.status_code == 200:
            cars = get_content(html.text)
            return cars
        else:
            print('Error')
    
    
    parse()
```

Comment: Так у вас вывод замментирован

Answer (score 0):

В строке с `return cars` вы просто возвращаете значение, которое потом не используете (в последней строке `parse()`). Попробуйте заменить `return cars` на `print(cars)` или в последней строке `parse()` на `print(parse())`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.avito.ru/schelkovo/avtomobili/audi/a6-ASgBAgICAkTgtg3elyjitg3onSg?cd=1&radius=200'
HEADERS = {
    'user-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,/;q=0.8'
}
HOST = 'https://www.avito.ru/'


def get_html(url, params=''):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r


def get_content(html):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='iva-item-root-Nj_hb')
    cars = []
    for item in items:
        cars.append({
            'title':
            item.find('div', class_='iva-item-titleStep-_CxvN').find_next(
                'a').find_next('h3').get_text(strip=True),
            'link':
            item.find(
                'div',
                class_='iva-item-titleStep-_CxvN').find_next('a').get('href'),
            'price':
            item.find('span', class_='price-text-E1Y7h').get_text(),
            'facts':
            item.find('div', class_='iva-item-text-_s_vh').get_text(),
            'city':
            item.find(
                'div',
                class_='geo-georeferences-Yd_m5').find_next('span').get_text(),
        })
    return cars


def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    #print(html.content) #непосредственно всё, что находится на странице
    #print(html.headers.get('content-type')) #узнать то, в каком виде зашифрована информация
    if html.status_code == 200:
        cars = get_content(html.text)
        return cars
    else:
        print('Error')


print(parse())
```